# Complexity of solving linear equations plus disequality constraints $a \ne b$

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, matrices, computational-complexity

Let $K$ be ring and $S$ linear homogeneous system with $n$ variables $x_i$ over $K$.

Add to $K$ linear disequalities of the form $x_k \ne x_l$
and let the final system be $S'$.  If $K=\mathbb{F}_2$,
$S'$ is efficiently solvable since $$x_k \ne x_l \iff x_k = x_l +1$$

> Q1 What is the complexity of solving $S'$ for $K=\mathbb{Z}$?

> Q2 What is the complexity of solving $S'$ for $K=\mathbb{Z}/N \mathbb{Z}, N >2$?

We believe the answer to Q1 is polynomial time and the answer to Q2 to be
NP-hard.

Tractability for fixed $N$ will be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

1. Let $A\in M_{m,n}(\mathbb{Z})$; we consider an equation in the form $AX=0$ where $X\in \mathbb{Z}^n$. Let $r=rank(A)$.

We write the Smith Form of $A$: $A=P^{-1}SQ^{-1}$ where $S$ is pseudo-diagonal and $P,Q\in GL(\mathbb{Z})$. Then $SQ^{-1}X=0$ or $SY=0$ with $X=QY$. We obtain, up to order, $Y=[0_r,y_1,\cdots,y_{n-r}]^T$ where the $(y_j)$ are the parameters of the general solution. Finally, the $(x_i)_{i\leq n}$ are known linear combinations of the $(y_j)$ and the complexity of the calculation is polynomial.

Each condition $x_k\not= x_l$ is equivalent to a forbidden linear relation $R_{k,l}=0$ between the $(y_j)$. Using  -for example- the "isolve" command of Maple, we can obtain a parameterization of the solutions of $R_{k,l}=0$ in the form $y_j=f_j(z_1,\cdots,z_{n-r-1})$. Yet, such a parameterization does not seem very useful because the parameters change with the relations $R_{k,l}$.

2. $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ is not a PID, except when $N$ is a prime. We consider the case when $N=p_1\cdots p_k$ where the $(p_i)$ are distinct primes. Then it suffices to solve the system over each $\mathbb{Z}/p_i\mathbb{Z}$. In the sequel, we assume that $N=p$ is a prime.

Of course, the set of solutions is finite. I don't know if you want the list of all solutions or just the number of solutions... for example

let $p=17,n=10,r=4$. A test gives the following results:
without any inequations, there are $17^6=24,137,569$ solutions. With $2$ inequations, there are $21,381,376$ solutions.

Since $K$ is a field, it is easy to calculate the solutions without any inequations. We may choose the $n-r$ parameters among the $(x_i)$ and the other $(x_i)$ are linear combinations of the previous ones.

About the inequations $x_k\not= x_l$, if we don't want to be satisfied with forbidden equations, then we can transform them into equations in 2 different ways:

$\bullet$ $(x_k-x_l)^{p-1}=1$. We add an equation of degree $p-1$ and we don't add any unknown.

$\bullet$. $(x_k-x_l)k=1$. We add an equation of degree $2$ and an unknown $k$.

We can solve the system using the Grobner basis theory; however, the complexity can become very large with $n, p$.

EDIT. Answer to joro

No, the case when $p=3$ works correctly. For example, let $n=20,r=15$.

We use Grobner's theory and the method $(x_k-x_l)^{p-1}=1$; a test with $6$ inequations gives the following result

The list of $32$ solutions is displayed in $8$ seconds.

If we only want to know the number of solutions, then the result is displayed in $0.2$ second.

If $p=5$ or more generally if $p>3$, then the calculation is longer but is feasible if the number of solutions is of the order of a few tens.

.

Comment: Thanks. You don't give efficient solution with disequalities over F_3, right? Groebner basis are inefficient in general.

Comment: @joro, cf. my edit.

Comment: Few tens appears rather small. Solution for $n > 2$ will solve the NP-complete problem edge coloring of graph. For each vertex of $G$ with incident edges $X,Y,Z$.
Add the 3 disequalites $X \ne Y, X \ne Z, Y \ne Z$. Solution will give 3 edge coloring of $G$, which is NP-complete.